# Setting up mail delivery to Django on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, python, django

I have a server running Python 2.7 and Django 1.6. I'd like to allow Django to send and receive emails with as little overhead as possible. I'd prefer not to even have a Mailbox set up for Django. Ideally when a message comes in, it would just call a Django method with the content of the message.

I've been reading up on Ubuntu [mail servers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer) but they make it sound like an incredibly complicated process, and I'd prefer to not bog my server down with unnecessary processes.

Does anyone know of a good way to accomplish this? If it matters, everything is running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to send emails across the internet, and not just transfer some text files from one system to another via some other process (http:// ftp://), you'll need a mailserver somewhere that can receive mails.

This can be a google mail account or an account with your ISP/hosting provider, if you don't want to run one on your django server.

You can then have your django app log in to that account, check if there are any new mails, and deal with them accordingly.

There are probably some libraries out there which will make this process fairly easy.
It should be as simple as supplying account credentials, server address, and retrieving a list of messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive mails directly by your django app, you have to write a fully smtp-server and **THIS** is a "*incredibly complicated process*".

Best practice is setup a smtp server (ex. postfix) create a inbox for your django app and write some line of codes which poll this inbox.